# Permutation & Combinations - Distribution

Tags: permutations

The number of ways in which n distinct things can be distributed among n people so that at least one person does not get anything is 232. Find n.
I think every object has (n-1) option. So (n-1)^n=232. But this gives the answer as 4.4(not a whole number) whereas the answer is 4.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: I assume the $n$ people are distinct, is the same true for the things?

Comment: Yes. The question says "n distinct things".

Comment: Your formula is finding the distributions so that Bob does not get anything. You are missing all the distributions in which Bob gets something but some other person does not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are $n!$ ways in which everyone gets a thing. There are $n^n$ distributions in total.

Hence the formula for what you want is $n^n-n!$.

We start trying with $n=4$ and get $4^4-4!=232$. So we have found it.

Comment: Nicely explained.

Comment: Simple explanation. +1